# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified with tomcat -9.0.37

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I downloaded the windows service installer of version  9.0.37.But at the time of connecting tomcat with eclipse IDE which is of version 2020-06 it is showing error that the version of tomcat was unspecified.

[image]

So please help me how can I configure my eclipse with tomcat-9.0.37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [WTP Tomcat FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F): "To support searching for Tomcat runtimes, the contents of each directory being tested is checked for a set of content that uniquely identifies the version of Tomcat. These sets are based on the standard zip or tar.gz downloads from Apache. The packaged install for various versions of Linux (and even for other Operating Systems) might not quite match the expected set of files."

So get and unpack the zip file from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi in a folder your user owns and use that instead (with its own port numbers or after disabling your Tomcat service).

Comment: I face same issue, but I am setting tomcat from tomcat_instance_1 folder, I already have another  application using Tomcat home directory, basically I am trying to run multiple instance of tomcat. But while setting tomcat from tomcat_instance folder I see this error, home directory I am able to set..

Answer (score 8):

Look, you need to atleast open the folder once.

It will ask you the permission to enter after which it's contents will be visible to u as well as Eclipse.

So, after setting up and installing Tomcat, just go into the folder once, open it & then try connecting from Eclipse.

Instead of changing permissions, try this once!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Later when I tried accessing the Tomcat folder from the file explorer, it said you need permissions to access this folder. This made me realize that the folder is in **read-only** mode.
So in the file explorer, right-click on Tomcat 9.0 folder, go to **properties**, click on the **checkbox** beside Read-only to deselect it and then click on **OK**.
Then again try the **add server** process in eclipse. It should work now.

Tomcat folder is in the following location :

**C-> Program Files -> Apache Software Foundation**

or wherever you have installed Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had first downloaded the .exe file in apache website and I had this same issue. I tried to change the permissions but it did not work so I went back to apache website and **downloaded the .zip file**. I extracted it to the same folder I have eclipse and closed and opened eclipse again. It worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

You've to specify where the tomcat is, it can be from

a) Program files

**C >> Program Files >> Apache Software Foundation**

b) If tomcat is downloaded and you've zip,
Specify the Tomcat file location, don't select bin/conf folder, Tomcat won't be recognized but specify the folder of Tomcat Downloaded.

Doing any of these you can add sever in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

just try to enter C-> Program Files -> Apache Software Foundation -> tomcat ->bin and make sure there are files installed in this folder.
after that you can add the server in eclipse it will work.